# SVN Password free read and write access

Tags: svn, unix

SVN Gurus,

I wish to create a repo where in I am not prompted for password upon checkout and commit.

I understand that it's possible to give no password in checkout by creating anonymous read. How can one ensure that any one can also do commits without being prompted for password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the protocol you're using to access the repo. Read http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.auth for `svn://` access, and http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authn for `http://` access.

Basically, it's just a matter of defining `anon-access = write` in svnserve.conf (for `svn://` access), and not defining any `AuthType` in httpd.conf for `http://` access (using Apache).